# Paging gridview with next, previous button and display page number of total page using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have done everything in grid view. One more requirement is there. That is  next, previous button and display page number of total page using asp.net Ex:I need to dispaly  Page 4 of 10  same row. Actually I have written code that it displaying Page 4 of 10 **Code for .aspx.cs is below**
 `protected void gvformlist_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Page " + (gvformlist.PageIndex + 1) + " of " + gvformlist.PageCount;
            }
        }` but it is only displaying Page number and total number of pages but in same pager i need both button and page number like Page 3 of 10. What  should i do?  **code for .aspx is below**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvformlist" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No results match the specified search criteria"
                OnRowDataBound="gvformlist_RowDataBound" PagerSettings-Position="Top" AllowPaging="true" ShowHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" AllowSorting="true" CssClass="gv" OnPageIndexChanging="gvformlist_PageIndexChanging">
                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First " NextPageText="Next " PreviousPageText="Previous " LastPageText="Last " />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" />
```

Comment: that's actually explained [in the MSDN example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.bottompagerrow(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2): Look at `Label pageLabel` in the sample code

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `ShowFooter="true"` to the gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
       e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Page " + (GridView1.PageIndex + 1) + " of " + GridView1.PageCount;
    }
}
```